# Flaw in the strcpy sample program

Tags: c, pointers

I am using the following code to copy the string contents to another string.
Two logics are used ,One with while loop(commented) is working and the other is not (as=at).

Please help me to identify the flaw in this code.

Thanks in advance

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    char *s="SourceString";
    char *t="TargetString";

    void print(char *s);
    void strcopy(char *s,const char *t);
    print(s);

    strcopy(s,t);
    print(s);
    getch();
}

void strcopy(char *as,const char *at)
{
    /*while((*as=*at)!='\0')    // working
    {
        as++;
        at++;
    }  */
    as=at;    //not working
}

void print(char *s)
{
    printf("\n Printing the Contents:");
    for(;*s!='\0';s++)
        printf("%c",*s);
    printf("\n END");
}
```

All are saying that the strings are passed by Value and not by address.
But I am passng the address of the strings in calling functiona nd in called function am using pointers.
Please clarify I am new to pointers

Answer (score 2):

When `as` is a function argument, writing `as=anything;` ceases to have effect when the function terminates, because its arguments cease to exist (as well as its local variables). You are not modifying the string, you are only modifying a memory cell that was temporarily containing the address of the string, and which was going to be released anyway.

Your question is really a question about pointers. Perhaps you can find an already asked question on StackOverflow about pointers in C or C++ that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a string like this:

```
char *s="SourceString";
```

is using readonly memory so modifing the contents will result in undefined behaviour. Using arrays will probably work as you thought.

```
char s[]="SourceString";
char t[]="TargetString";
```

In your example, you are just playing with local variables which get destroyed when the strcpy function returns.

You could try something like this:

```
void strcopy2(char **s, char **t) //<--- pointers to pointers, ouch!
{
    *t = *s; //<--- Assign the value of the pointer who's address was passed.
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "SourceString";
    char *t = "TargetString";

    printf("%s\n", s);
    strcopy2(&s, &t);  //<--- pass address of pointers!
    printf("%s\n", t);

}
```

I prefer to use char arrays though if i'm manipulating strings.

Comment: Oh, good point. And double good point for noticing that the string "TargetString" was the one that was read and "SourceString" the one written to.

Answer (score 1):

The version that works uses a loop to copy one character at a time.

The version that doesn't just copies one pointer variable to another. This operation doesn't affect anything else in the program. `as = at` just modifies one local variable and returns. So that is not an optimization that you can make.

Answer (score 0):

With `as=at;` you copy local variable into local variable. Never mind that they are pointers - they are copies on the function's stack, so your changes are not visible outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two errors with your non working code.

1) Your statement *as = at* copies a local variable onto another local.  The assignment is lost once you leave the function.
2) You are probably leaking whatever *as* pointed to before the assignment,

Another potential problem in usage is that  usually in C we say *target <- source* so that your usage of *as* and *at* looks backwards.